# run an object against xml and print xml attributes python

Tags: python, xml

How can I run `number = 9` against this `xml` list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <class name="Chemicals" number="1" description="Chemicals used in industry, science and photography, as well as in agriculture, horticulture and forestry;
            unprocessed artificial resins, unprocessed plastics; manures; fire extinguishing compositions;
            tempering and soldering preparations; chemical substances for preserving foodstuffs; tanning substances;
            adhesives used in industry">
    </class>
    <class name="Paints" number="2" description="Paints, varnishes, lacquers; preservatives against rust and against deterioration of wood; colorants; mordants;
            raw natural resins; metals in foil and powder form for painters, decorators, printers and artists.
            Explanatory Note This class includes mainly paints, colorants and preparations used for the protection against corrosion.
            Includes, in particular: paints, varnishes and lacquers for industry, handicrafts and arts; dyestuffs for clothing;
            colorants for foodstuffs and beverages.">
    </class>
    <class name="Cosmetics and cleaning preparations" number="3" description="Bleaching preparations and other substances for laundry use; cleaning, polishing, scouring and abrasive preparations;
            soaps; perfumery, essential oils, cosmetics, hair lotions; dentifrices.">
    </class>
    <class name="Lubricants and fuels" number="4" description="Industrial oils and greases; lubricants; dust absorbing, wetting and binding compositions;
            fuels (including motor spirit) and illuminants; candles, wicks.">
    </class>
    <class name="Pharmaceuticals" number="5" description="Pharmaceutical, veterinary and sanitary preparations; dietetic substances adapted for medical use, food for babies;
            plasters, materials for dressings; material for stopping teeth, dental wax; disinfectants;
            preparations for destroying vermin; fungicides, herbicides.">
    </class>
    <class name="Metal goods" number="6" description="Common metals and their alloys; metal building materials; transportable buildings of metal; materials of metal for railway tracks;
            non-electric cables and wires of common metal; iron mongery, small items of metal hardware; pipes and tubes of metal; safes;
            goods of common metal not included in other classes; ores.">
    </class>
    <class name="Machinery" number="7" description="Machines and machine tools; motors and engines (except for land vehicles); machine coupling and transmission components (except for land vehicles);
            agricultural implements other than hand-operated; incubators for eggs">
    </class>
    <class name="Hand tools" number="8" description="Hand tools and implements (hand operated); cutlery; side arms; razors.">
    </class>
    <class name="Electrical and scientific apparatus" number="9" description="Scientific, nautical, surveying, electric, photographic, cinematographic, optical, weighing, measuring, signaling, checking (supervision), lifesaving and teaching apparatus and instruments;
            apparatus for recording, transmission or reproduction of sound or images; magnetic data carriers, recording discs; automatic vending machines and mechanisms for coin operated apparatus;
            cash registers, calculating machines, data processing equipment and computers; fire-extinguishing apparatus.">
    </class>
    <class name="Medial Apparatus" number="10" description="Surgical, medical, dental and veterinary apparatus and instruments, artificial limbs, eyes and teeth; orthopedic articles; suture materials.">
    </class>
    <class name="Environmental control apparatus" number="11" description="Apparatus for lighting, heating, steam generating, cooking, refrigerating, drying, ventilating, water supply and sanitary purposes">
    </class>
    <class name="Vehicles" number="12" description="Vehicles; apparatus for locomotion by land, air or water.">
    </class>
    <class name="Firearms" number="13" description="Firearms; ammunition and projectiles; explosives; fireworks.">
    </class>
    <class name="Jewelry" number="14" description=" Precious metals and their alloys and goods in precious metals or coated therewith, not included in other classes; jewelry, precious stones;">
    </class>
    <class name="Musical Instruments" number="15" description="Musical Instruments.">
    </class>
    <class name="Paper goods and printed matter" number="16" description="Paper, cardboard and goods made from these materials, not included in other classes; printed matter; bookbinding material;
            photographs; stationery; adhesives for stationery or household purposes; artists' materials; paint brushes;
            typewriters and office requisites (except furniture); instructional and teaching material (except apparatus);
            plastic materials for packaging (not included in other classes); playing cards; printers' type; printing blocks.">
    </class>
    <class name="Rubber Goods" number="17" description="Rubber, gutta-percha, gum, asbestos, mica and goods made from these materials and not included in other classes;
            plastics in extruded form for use in manufacture; packing, stopping and insulating materials; flexible pipes, not of metal">
    </class>
    <class name="Leather Goods" number="18" description="Leather and imitations of leather, and goods made of these materials and not included in other classes; animal skins, hides;
            trunks and traveling bags; umbrellas, parasols and walking sticks; whips, harness and saddlery">
    </class>
    <class name="Nonmetallic building materials" number="19" description="Building materials (nonmetallic); nonmetallic rigid pipes for building; asphalt, pitch and bitumen; nonmetallic transportable buildings; monuments, not of metal.">
    </class>
    <class name="Furniture and articles not otherwise classified" number="20" description="Furniture, mirrors, picture frames; goods (not included in other classes) of wood, cork, reed, cane, wicker, horn, bone, ivory, whalebone, shell, amber, mother-of-pearl, meerschaum and substitutes for all these materials, or of plastics.">
    </class>
    <class name="Housewares and glass" number="21" description="Household or kitchen utensils and containers (not of precious metal or coated therewith); combs and sponges; brushes (except paint brushes); brush-making materials; articles for cleaning purposes; steel wool;
            un-worked or semi-worked glass (except glass used in building); glassware, porcelain and earthenware not included in other classes.">
    </class>
    <class name="Cordage and fibers" number="22" description="Ropes, string, nets, tents, awnings, tarpaulins, sails, sacks and bags (not included in other classes); padding and stuffing materials (except of rubber or plastics); raw fibrous textile materials.">
    </class>
    <class name="Yarns and threads" number="23" description="Yarns and threads, for textile use">
    </class>
    <class name="Fabrics" number="24" description="Textiles and textile goods, not included in other classes; bed and table covers">
    </class>
    <class name="Clothing" number="25" description="Clothing, footwear, headgear">
    </class>
    <class name="Fancy goods" number="26" description="Lace and embroidery, ribbons and braid; buttons, hooks and eyes, pins and needles; artificial flowers">
    </class>
    <class name="Floor coverings" number="27" description="Carpets, rugs, mats and matting, linoleum and other materials for covering existing floors; wall hangings (non-textile).">
    </class>
    <class name="Toys and sporting goods" number="28" description="Games and playthings; gymnastic and sporting articles not included in other classes; decorations for Christmas trees.">
    </class>
    <class name="Meats and Processed Foods" number="29" description="Meat, fish, poultry and game; meat extracts; preserved, dried and cooked fruits and vegetables; jellies, jams, fruit sauces; eggs, milk and milk products; edible oils and fats.">
    </class>
    <class name="Staple Foods" number="30" description="Coffee, tea, cocoa, sugar, rice, tapioca, sago, artificial coffee; flour and preparations made from cereals, bread, pastry and confectionery, ices; honey, treacle; yeast, baking-powder;
            salt, mustard; vinegar, sauces (condiments); spices; ice.">
    </class>
    <class name="Natural Agricultural Products" number="31" description="Agricultural, horticultural and forestry products and grains not included in other classes; living animals; fresh fruits and vegetables; seeds, natural plants and flowers; foodstuffs for animals, malt.">
    </class>
    <class name="Light beverages" number="32" description="Beers; mineral and aerated waters and other nonalcoholic drinks; fruit drinks and fruit juices; syrups and other preparations for making beverages.">
    </class>
    <class name="Wine and Spirits" number="33" description="Alcoholic beverages (except beers).">
    </class>
    <class name="Smoker's articles" number="34" description="Tobacco; smokers' articles; matches.">
    </class>
    <class name="Advertising and business" number="35" description="Advertising; business management; business administration; office functions.">
    </class>
    <class name="Insurance and Financial" number="36" description="Insurance; financial affairs; monetary affairs; real estate affairs.">
    </class>
    <class name="Building construction and repair" number="37" description="Building construction; repair; installation services.">
    </class>
    <class name="Telecommunications" number="38" description="Telecommunications">
    </class>
    <class name="Transport and storage" number="39" description="Transport; packaging and storage of goods; travel arrangement.">
    </class>
    <class name="Treatment of materials" number="40" description="Treatment of materials">
    </class>
    <class name="Education and entertainment" number="41" description="Education; providing of training; entertainment; sporting and cultural activities">
    </class>
    <class name="Computer, scientific and legal" number="42" description="Scientific and technological services and research and design relating thereto: industrial analysis and research services; design and development of computer hardware and software; legal services">
    </class>
    <class name="Hotels and Restaurants" number="43" description="Services for providing food and drink; temporary accommodations.">
    </class>
    <class name="Medical, beauty and agricultural" number="44" description="Medical services; veterinary services; hygienic and beauty care for human beings or animals; agriculture, horticulture and forestry services">
    </class>
    <class name="Personal" number="45" description="Personal and social services rendered by others to meet the needs of individuals; security services for the protection of property and individuals">
    </class>
</data>
```

So I can return class -> name, number, description, so for a given number find correct `class` in `xml` file and return it's content, I know how to parse `xml` file but I'm not sure how to run this `number` against it so I can return `class` content, can someone please help me understand this, thanks.

Comment: What are TrademarkAnalyzeEachLineTestData, TrademarkOpenClassToReadWordsToArray, TrademarkOpenFileReadWords? And can you edit your question because it is duplicated.

Comment: @ands I've rephrase everything, because it was confusing for me to, it's rather simple question, and I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


def get_data(url, timeout = 15):
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    ''' function returns html of url
    usually data = urlopen(url) is enough but sometimes it doesn't work
    also instead urllib.request you can use any other method to get data
    of url like urllib or urllib2 (just search it online), but I
    think urllib.request comes with python installation'''

    data = ''
    try:
        data = urlopen(url, None, timeout)
    except:
        url = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        try:
            data = urlopen(url, None, timeout)
        except:
            pass
    return data

path = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/4nds/stackoverflow/master/trademark.xml'
xml_open = get_data(path)

tree = ET.parse(xml_open)
root = tree.getroot()

data_dict = dict()
for element in root:
    elm_dict = dict(element.items())
    data_dict.update({int(elm_dict['number']): elm_dict})
#print(data_dict)
print(data_dict[1])
```

the result (of my code) is:

```
{'name': 'Chemicals', 'number': '1', 'description': 'Chemicals used in industry, science and photography, as well as in agriculture, horticulture and forestry;             unprocessed artificial resins, unprocessed plastics; manures; fire extinguishing compositions;             tempering and soldering preparations; chemical substances for preserving foodstuffs; tanning substances;             adhesives used in industry'}
```

You can ignore function get_data(), I am using it just for opening online xml file, but if you already have a file you can just use `xml_open = open(<your file>, 'r')`.

I hope this helps.

Edit after [PetarP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860850/run-an-object-against-xml-and-print-xml-attributes-python/45862387?noredirect=1#comment78690879_45862387):

I am not sure I understand what you want, but if you want to get description for a trademark with specific number (for example 39) you can use:

```
print(data_dict[30]['description'])
```

then you will get:

```
Coffee, tea, cocoa, sugar, rice, tapioca, sago, artificial coffee; flour and preparations made from cereals, bread, pastry and confectionery, ices; honey, treacle; yeast, baking-powder;             salt, mustard; vinegar, sauces (condiments); spices; ice.
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, but I need to return trademark description for a given result, so when the result is 30 I need to run it against that xml and print everything for `class 30`